# Deploying iPhone Apps to Real Devices

Tags: iphone

I bought developer account,now how can i register my app and install it in real iphone ?

Answer (score 1):

After login to your developer account, you will get "iPhone developer program user guide" (the name might be changed a little. I don't have a developer access right now). This is a long guide and describes everything that you need step by step, from creating a certificate to make a submission build. You really need to read this. There are lots of things to do and it's difficult to explain everything correctly in short notes.

Comment: You really have to carefully read all the steps in the iOS Development Guide, and double check whether you've followed them exactly as described.

Answer (score 0):

1.Log in to the [iPhone developer center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/)

2.Click on "iPhone provisioning portal"

3.Click on "launch assistant"

4.Follow the steps

Comment: i did this but at the end when i set device and build occur below error

Code sign error : the identity 'iphone developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/privarte key pair in the default keychain

Comment: It will works if you download the appropriate certificate(s), and provisioning profiles and set the target build settings accordingly but the "Organizer" way is a lot easier.

Comment: i use the "Organizer" but it doesn't work
please give me explain step by step

Comment: I get to cite it-crowd: "Have you tried to turn it off and on again?" 

When I get problems with provisioning it usually works.

Comment: after i follow steps in "launch assistant" should i enter any code,... to xcode ?(means enter sth(sign code,...) to build page(info->build) of my app)

Answer (score 0):

From XCode, click Menu Window/Organizer, right click your device in Device List on the left and select "Add Device to provisioning portal" and do what it says.  That will automatically do all the stuff that needs to be done for you.

Comment: i do some steps but nothing happen please explain more
thank you

Comment: did the wizard executed nomrmaly without error ?  If not, which error do you have.  If yes, what is your problem now ?  Have you set the proper code signing identity in Xcode ?

Comment: after i click add Device to... want username and password and then nothing happen

Comment: You are supposed to see a progress bar in the summary tab even before it asks for un/pwd.  Do you see it ?

Are you using Xcode 3.2.3 ?

Comment: yes i see progress bar after it enter un/pwd and after it show progress bar again and then noithing happen

Comment: if the progress bar disapear without any error message, then everything ran just fine.  You just need to set the appropriate code signing in Xcode.  Select your main (only) target, click the info button and go on the Build Tab.  There you should find the Code Signing Section.  Set the Code Signing identity to iPhone Developer (Automatic profile).

Comment: you mean doesn't necessary use keychine,goto developer.apple.com/iphone and other just "Add Device to provisioning portal" and then enter 'iphone developer in code signing and set Device then build project ?
but it doesn't work and occur above error

Comment: Then go to developer.apple.com in provisioning portal and download your development certificate and development provisioning profile.  You might also download the WWDR certificate.  ALso check that your device is present in the device list.